# CakePHPのViewにMySQLのJSONデータを渡して管理画面(Table)を作成する方法

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp, json

データのWeb管理画面を作成しています。

【現在の状況】
管理者ログイン画面は作成しました。またログイン後に、CakePHPとで取得したテーブル情報を、JSONでViewに送信するところはできています。

【やりたいこと】
取得した JSON ファイルをもとに、管理テーブルを作成したいです。
イメージとして、各行には、取得した情報と、ステータスを操作するためのボタンがついています。ボタンを押すと、アクションを実行(パラメータに、押した箇所のid)して、特定のカラムの数値を変更するイメージです。どのような技術で、実現できるのか教えていただけますとありがたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どんなデータを渡されるのかがわかりませんが･･･
こんなデータを想定します。JSONデータをJavaScript側で扱えるようにするには`parseJSON`を使います。

```
{
    "list": 
    [
        {"name": "taro", "age": "28"},
        {"name": "jiro", "age": "26"}
    ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var jsonData = $.parseJSON('{"list": [{"name": "taro", "age": "28"},{"name": "jiro", "age": "26"}]}');

    for(var idx=0; idx < jsonData.list.length; idx++ ){
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append('<td class="name">'+jsonData.list[idx].name);
        tr.append('<td class="age">'+jsonData.list[idx].age);
        tr.append('<td><input type="button" class="button" value="button">');
        $('#target').find('tbody').append(tr);
    }

    $('.button').on('click', function(){
        var element = $(this).parents('tr').find('.name').text();
        $('body').append(element+'<br />');
    });
});
</script>

<table id="target">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

必要と思われる技術は入れてますので、よく分からなければこれをとっかかりに学んでください。
あとはやりたいことをソースをつけてピンポイントで質問していってください。

Comment: 貴重なアドバイス(ソース)ありがとうございます。JavaScriptですね。
こちらをもとに、勉強してみます。また、次回はソースもつけて質問させていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @tomojiro さん JavaScriptのjQueryというライブラリを使用しています。混乱するといけないので一応･･･